# Can a child post an app to the app store?

Tags: apple-id, app-store-connect

I am 11 years old, and I have made an app I want to post to the App Store. Is there any way to do that, or do I have to use my mom's account? (I have an Apple id because of Family Sharing)

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6441831?start=0&tstart=0 ;)

Comment: Please post this as an answer :)

Comment: Of course, your Stack Exchange account is registered under your mom's email address, and you have not used your *real* name on this site. This is the case, therefore the site moderators don't have to delete your personal information - and therefore your ability to log in - to comply with US legislation. **If you are using your own details, see the comments on [this SO meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320691/5223757) for how to save your account.**

Comment: I have changed my name to a nickname. Will it be ok now, because I have tried a lot to get 142 reputation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Apple discussions thread [can i be an apple developer under 18?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6441831?start=0&tstart=0) is exactly what your are looking for :

> No. An adult would have to do that for you. To have a developer
>   account you must be 18 or older.

…

> You can always start a corporation and the individual age restriction
>   is not relevant anymore.

Comment: CEO at 11 years old. The parents would be proud.

Comment: As a counterpoint: I did it at Suryan's age. It's entirely possible. Cooperation from parents is nice to have, and a certain minimal amount is required (gotta get that first $100 from somewhere)... but no one is looking over your shoulder. I'm not a lawyer, and if you get thrown in jail it's not my fault, but... seriously, Apple doesn't have the budget to go around enforcing that age limit, and they have no reason to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Strictly speaking you need to register as a developer and to do that as an individual you need to meet minimum age requirements. Typically this is 18, although it could be different in various countries.

Also, depending on your jurisdiction, there may be other requirements you must meet before being able to register as a developer.

In your case, you could have a parent register and then use their developer account. When uploading an app you need to complete a number of metadata fields, one of which is who the app is copyrighted to. So you could still put your name in that field.

Another option is to set up a company (or something similar) in which case there wouldn't be the age restriction. However, depending on your jurisdiction there could be an age requirement for registration of a company.

A good place to start (if you haven't already) is to explore https://developer.apple.com for answers to your questions.